# Angular 2/4 FormControl in FormGroup not able to display on form with label

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am not understanding how to do

1. console.log of a specific value
2. display in a label on HTML page
3. display in an input text

Here is my Component Typescript with new FormGroup and then the new FormControls

```
    this.trackerForm = new FormGroup({
        session: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        date: new FormControl(new Date(), [
            Validators.required
        ]),
        contactType: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required
        ]),
        customerType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(80)]),
        lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(80)]),
        phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10)]),
        extension: new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(7)])

    });

    // this outputs the entire json
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.trackerForm.value));
    //How do I ONLY console.log  one of the values?   date?
```

HTML on page -

```
<form [formGroup]="trackerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(trackerForm.value)" novalidate>

 <div>
      <label class="form-control"><span>{{trackerForm.date.value}}  </span></label>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<label class="form-control"><span>{{trackerForm.value.date | date:'short'}}  </span></label>`

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. But if you want to display the value of a single field you can do `console.log(this.trackerForm.get('fieldName').value);`

Comment: And in a html page it's the same `{{trackerForm.get('fieldName').value}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<form [formGroup]="trackerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(trackerForm.value)" novalidate>

 <div>
      <label class="form-control"><span>{{trackerForm.get('date').value}}  </span></label>
    </div>
```

or

```
<label class="form-control"><span>{{trackerForm.controls['date'].value}}  </span></label>
```

but the first one the definitely better because 'AOT' doesn't compile the second one.

but I would create a component `getter` to make it nicer :

```
 get dateControl(){
     return this.trackerForm.get('date');
 }
```

and then :

```
    <form [formGroup]="trackerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(trackerForm.value)" novalidate>

 <div>
      <label class="form-control"><span>{{dateControl.value}}  </span></label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works with mat-card-title also. Thank you!  <mat-card-title>{{formattedUsers.get('name').value}}</mat-card-title>

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `formGroup` controls via `trackerForm.controls` object.

Example for `"date"` control's value `trackerForm.controls['date'].value`.